# Python find duplicated dicts in list and separate them with counting

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set

I have a dicts in a list and some dicts are identical. I want to find duplicated ones and want to add to new list or dictionary with how many duplicate they have.

```
import itertools

myListCombined = list()
for a, b in itertools.combinations(myList, 2):
    is_equal = set(a.items()) - set(b.items())
    if len(is_equal) == 0:
        a.update(count=2)
        myListCombined.append(a)
    else:
        a.update(count=1)
        b.update(count=1)
        myListCombined.append(a)
        myListCombined.append(b)

myListCombined = [i for n, i enumerate(myListCombine) if i not in myListCombine[n + 1:]]
```

This code is kinda working, but it's just for 2 duplicated dicts in list. a.update(count=2) won't work in this situations.
I'm also deleting duplicated dicts after separete them in last line, but i'm not sure if it's going to work well.

Input:

```
[{'name': 'Mary', 'age': 25, 'salary': 1000},
{'name': 'John', 'age': 25, 'salary': 2000},
{'name': 'George', 'age': 30, 'salary': 2500},
{'name': 'John', 'age': 25, 'salary': 2000},
{'name': 'John', 'age': 25, 'salary': 2000}]
```

Desired Output:

```
[{'name': 'Mary', 'age': 25, 'salary': 1000, 'count':1},
{'name': 'John', 'age': 25, 'salary': 2000, 'count': 3},
{'name': 'George', 'age': 30, 'salary': 2500, 'count' 1}]
```

Comment: Please post your input and desired output.

Comment: edited, thanks @Ajax1234

Comment: Please see my response below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following, which first converts each dictionary to a frozenset of key,value tuples (so that they are hashable as required by collections.Counter).

```
import collections
a = [{'a':1}, {'a':1},{'b':2}]
print(collections.Counter(map(lambda x: frozenset(x.items()),a)))
```

**Edit to reflect your desired input/output:**

```
from copy import deepcopy

def count_duplicate_dicts(list_of_dicts):
    cpy = deepcopy(list_of_dicts)
    for d in list_of_dicts:
        d['count'] = cpy.count(d)
    return list_of_dicts

x = [{'a':1},{'a':1}, {'c':3}]
print(count_duplicate_dicts(x))
```

Comment: i stucked when i use collections.Counter as dicts are not hashable. Thanks for your help!
So as frozenset are not subscriptable, should i use `dict(frozenset)['salary']` to reach values?

Answer (score 0):

You can take the count values using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) and then rebuild the dicts after adding the count value from the `Counter` to each frozenset:

```
from collections import Counter

l = [dict(d | {('count', c)}) for d, c in Counter(frozenset(d.items()) 
                                                  for d in myList).items()]  
print(l)
# [{'salary': 1000, 'name': 'Mary', 'age': 25, 'count': 1}, 
#  {'name': 'John', 'salary': 2000, 'age': 25, 'count': 3}, 
#  {'salary': 2500, 'name': 'George', 'age': 30, 'count': 1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your dict data is well structured and the contents of the dict are simple data types, e.g., numbers and string, and you have following data analysis processing, I would suggest you use pandas, which provide rich functions. Here is a sample code for your case:

```
In [32]: data = [{'name': 'Mary', 'age': 25, 'salary': 1000},
    ...: {'name': 'John', 'age': 25, 'salary': 2000},
    ...: {'name': 'George', 'age': 30, 'salary': 2500},
    ...: {'name': 'John', 'age': 25, 'salary': 2000},
    ...: {'name': 'John', 'age': 25, 'salary': 2000}]
    ...: 
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    ...: df['counts'] = 1
    ...: df = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()[:-1]).sum().reset_index(drop=False)
    ...: 

In [33]: df
Out[33]: 
   age    name  salary  counts
0   25    John    2000       3
1   25    Mary    1000       1
2   30  George    2500       1

In [34]: df.to_dict(orient='records')
Out[34]: 
[{'age': 25, 'counts': 3, 'name': 'John', 'salary': 2000},
 {'age': 25, 'counts': 1, 'name': 'Mary', 'salary': 1000},
 {'age': 30, 'counts': 1, 'name': 'George', 'salary': 2500}]
```

The logical are:

(1) First build the DataFrame from your data

(2) The groupby function can do aggregate function on each group.

(3) To output back to dict, you can call `pd.to_dict`

Pandas is a big package, which costs some time to learn it, but it worths to know pandas. It is so powerful that can make your data analysis quite faster and elegant.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import collections

d = [{'name': 'Mary', 'age': 25, 'salary': 1000},
{'name': 'John', 'age': 25, 'salary': 2000},
{'name': 'George', 'age': 30, 'salary': 2500},
{'name': 'John', 'age': 25, 'salary': 2000},
{'name': 'John', 'age': 25, 'salary': 2000}]

count = dict(collections.Counter([i["name"] for i in d]))
a = list(set(map(tuple, [i.items() for i in d])))
final_dict = [dict(list(i)+[("count", count[dict(i)["name"]])]) for i in a]
```

Output:

```
[{'salary': 2000, 'count': 3, 'age': 25, 'name': 'John'}, {'salary': 2500, 'count': 1, 'age': 30, 'name': 'George'}, {'salary': 1000, 'count': 1, 'age': 25, 'name': 'Mary'}]
```